# Execute Anonymous error - Method does not exist or incorrect signature

Tags: execute-anonymous

I am trying to execute anonymous apex block. The method which is used here is also used in a trigger. Trigger is working fine. I am writing this apex code to update a new field based on the values of these fields REAC_TAC_BUSINESS_AREA__c,Tier__c,REAC_TAC_CATEGORY__c,queue1__c.This logic is inside the method.

Getting following error

> Line: 11, Column: 33 Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   void handlerbeforeupdate(Case)  from the type
>   REAC_TAC_CaseTriggerHandler

Here is the Apex code

```
Date myDate = date.newinstance(2017,12,4);
integer cnum  = 0;

For (case c: [select 
id,REAC_TAC_BUSINESS_AREA__c,Tier__c,REAC_TAC_CATEGORY__c,queue1__c from 
case where createddate > :myDate])
{
 system.debug('c.id'+c.id);
 system.debug('c.id'+c.REAC_TAC_BUSINESS_AREA__c);
 system.debug('c.id'+c.Tier__c);
 system.debug('c.id'+c.REAC_TAC_CATEGORY__c);
 cnum = cnum +1;    
 REAC_TAC_CaseTriggerHandler.handlerbeforeupdate(c);

}
update c;
system.debug('total cases:' + cnum);
```

Here is the class & method:

```
public class REAC_TAC_CaseTriggerHandler {
 -------
public static void handlerbeforeupdate(List<Case> cases) {
for (case c1 :cases){
```

Comment: You call it with single parameter, but method is defined with list of parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger helper is expecting a list of Cases, but you try to call it with one case. Try this instead:

```
REAC_TAC_CaseTriggerHandler.handlerbeforeupdate(new List<Case>{c});
```

But be aware that it is not bulkified anymore, so you might consider passing the list you queried and not do it in the for loop.

Calling the trigger **manually** should actually **not be necessary**, since it should be called automatically when you do your dml `update cases;`

```
List<Case> cases = [select 
id,REAC_TAC_BUSINESS_AREA__c,Tier__c,REAC_TAC_CATEGORY__c,queue1__c from 
case where createddate > :myDate];

For (case c: cases)
{
 system.debug('c.id'+c.id);
 system.debug('c.id'+c.REAC_TAC_BUSINESS_AREA__c);
 system.debug('c.id'+c.Tier__c);
 system.debug('c.id'+c.REAC_TAC_CATEGORY__c);
 cnum = cnum +1;
}

//REAC_TAC_CaseTriggerHandler.handlerbeforeupdate(cases);

update cases;
```

Comment: I updated my post. I modified as you mentioned. But i got error.

Comment: @UmaN you need to write `update cases;` instead of `update c;` fixed it in my answer. And please try to not post different question in one question, it will confuse people reading it afterwards.